# Check whether two String's are anagram

Tags: java, anagram

I wrote a method for checking whether two Strings are anagram or not. The method is returning true even if the words are not anagram. I don't see any bug in the code, any ideas how can I improve ? The method is as following,

```
public static boolean checkAnagram( String one, String two){

    if ( one.length() != two.length() ) 
        return false;

    char[] letters  = new char[128];

    for ( char c: one.toCharArray()){

        letters[c]++;
    } 


    for( int j =0; j < two.length(); j++){

        int c = (int) two.charAt(j);

        if( --letters[c] < 0) return false;

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly this algorithm works, but just my personal opinion: use `toCharArray()`, sort it alphabetically, then compare the arrays.

Comment: I know few other ways to do it, I just want to know why this little code is not working. This algorithm keeps track of character using their ASCII values.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/15045640/1079354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`letters` is a `char` array, so `letters[i]` can never be negative (the range of `char` is `0` to `2^16-1`). If you try to decrement it below 0, it will underflow to `Character.MAX_VALUE`. Change it to an `int[]`.

Comment: Thanks, I also find this when reviewing more closely.

Answer (score 1):

In the first `for` loop you are using:

```
letters[c]++;
```

when `c` is a `char`. 
In the other `for` loop you `cast` `c` to `int` by performing `(int)two.charAt(j)` before assigning it to `c`.

Also, you are getting `true` each time because you can't have a negative value in a `char` array, so at every index exists that `letters[index] >= 0`. You need to change the array to `int[128]`.