# Anagram method not returning correct value. Doesnt work for large Strings

Tags: java

This is my attempt at an Anagram method, and it's not returning the correct value. It won't work for large Strings.

```
public boolean IsAnagram(String s,String p)
{
    int flag=0;

    char c[]=s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char d[]=p.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    if(c.length!= d.length)
    {
        System.out.println("no");
        //return false;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<d.length;j++)
        {
            if(c[i]==d[j])
            {
                ++flag;

            }
        }
    }
    if(flag==c.length)
    {
       return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example string for which this is not working?

Comment: A simpler algorithm for checking anagrams is to sort the two arrays and create two sorted strings out of that... then you do simple string comparison

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to work once you have strings with multiple of the same character, because your loop checks the entirety of the second string. For example, if `c` has one 'a' but `d` has 5 'a's, `flag` will be incremented 5 times. Assuming the rest of the characters in `d` have a match in `c`, you will still get `flag == c.length`, but it would be a false equivalence. Another option is to count the number of each character in the two strings. Also you need to return false when you get two strings of different lengths. Not sure why you commented that out.

Comment: Note: `aab` is not an anagram of `abb` even though it has the same letters. I suspect the reason longer string don't work is; more chance for different numbers of the same character.

Comment: A standard way of doing this is to sort the letters in each string and see if the results are the same. You may use `String.toCharArray()`, `Arrays.sort(char[])` and `Arrays.equals(char[], char[])`.

Comment: Whenever i am trying to add two Strings with repetitive characters, the function returns false. for instance, "raju" and "arju" works fine.. but, "Strings" and "tringss" returns false.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use library functions, keep it as simple as possible, e.g.

```
public static boolean anagram(String s1, String s2) {
    char[] c1 = s1.toCharArray();
    char[] c2 = s2.toCharArray();
    if (c1.length != c2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    outer:
    for (char ch : c1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < c2.length; i++) {
            if (c2[i] == ch) {
                c2[i] = '\0';
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here you search for every char in the first array a matching char in the second one, and "cross it out", so you don't count it twice. Of course this assumes that you don't have `'\0'` chars in your strings (which would be quite unusual).

Try to avoid complicated "book-keeping", counters, flags etc. Focus on small, logical steps and invariants.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `break` here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
            if (c[i] == d[j]) {
                ++flag;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It helps. I expect more cases will work now. I suspect that `aab` and `abb` will be declared anagrams because they have the same length and all letters in the former are also in the latter. Even `aab` and `abc`.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Lawrey is right. You must not only check if the letter in the second array is there, you must also check that they appear same number of times. Sorting and comparing the Strings would be a good solution i think.

Here is a fancy solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004897/3959856

Comment: The linked solution is fancy alright — a bit too fancy for my personal preference. Why not just keep a count of each English letter and compare the counts in the end?

Comment: Then sorting and comparing is nicer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to solve a simple task in such a contrived way? Just use the API functions you already have:

```
public static boolean anagram(String s1, String s2) {
    char[] c1 = s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] c2 = s2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(c1);
    Arrays.sort(c2);
    return Arrays.equals(c1,c2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this... However, I was trying to solve the problem without using inbuilt API libraries.

Comment: @gauravJ see my second answer.

Answer (score -1):

Sum the characters if they are equal then strings are anagram

```
private boolean isAnagram(String s1, String s2) {

    char a[] = s1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char b[] = s2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    if (a.length == b.length) {
        int l = a.length; //or b.length
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            total += a[i];
            total -= b[i];
        }
        if (total == 0)
            return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: This has lots of false positives. For example, "ac" and "bb" aren't anagrams, yet your method would find that they are.