# Input: a word's string. Prints all rearrangements of the given string without repeating. JAVA

Tags: java, anagram

I'm trying to implement this in Java but I don't how to. Any suggestions?

Examples.

**input:**

abc

**output:**

abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba

**input:**

aab

**output:**

aab
aba
baa

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
Please show us what you have tried so far, and which part you are finding issue with ?

Comment: For starter: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-program-to-check-whether-two-strings-are-anagram-or-not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if two words are anagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045640/how-to-check-if-two-words-are-anagrams)

Comment: i don't know how to put my ideias into programming lenguage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the simplest way I could think of

```
 String str= "abc";
            ArrayList<String> letters = new ArrayList<String>();
            HashSet<String> combinations = new HashSet<String>();
            for(int i = 0; i<str.length();i++) {
//Break String into letters
                letters.add(str.substring(i,i+1));
            }
            for(int i = (str.length()*2)+1;i>0;i--) {
//Will loop through maximum possible outcomes
                String result = "";
                String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
//System.out.println(bin);
                while(bin.length()<3) {
                    bin="0"+bin;
                }
                for(int b = bin.length();b>0;b--) {
                    if(bin.substring(b-1,b).equals("1"))result = result.concat(letters.get(b-1));
                }
                for(int b = bin.length();b>0;b--) {
                    if(bin.substring(b-1,b).equals("0"))result = result.concat(letters.get(b-1));
                }
                combinations.add(result);
            }
            System.out.println(str);
            for(String c : combinations) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
```

It uses binary to loop through an array of the original string then adds the result to a hash set to remove duplicates

Comment: I need to study about ArrayList and HashSet. I've never heard about that.

Comment: @Fredgrub They are useful for storing and accessing multiple variable. There are some great resources in the JavaDocs as well as GoalKicker if you are interested in learning more