# I don´t find the mistake of my code to check strings for anagram

Tags: java, string, anagram

I have to write a code which should test, if string one is an anagram of another string. But my code doesn´t work. I get everytime false as result. Can anyone explain where is my mistake ?

```
public boolean anagram (String s1, String s2) {
    count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i !=-1; i++) {
        if(s1.indexOf(s2.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        count++;
        temp = Integer.toString(s1.indexOf(s2.charAt(i)));
        s1.replace(temp,"");
    } if(count+1 == s1.length())
        return a == true;
    }

    return a == false;
```

Comment: What is `a`? If `a` is true, what is `a == true`? Moreover, what is `a == false`?

Comment: @mkasberg Good point.

Comment: a is a boolean:
boolean a;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding if two words are anagrams of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236906/finding-if-two-words-are-anagrams-of-each-other)

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich And a much better answer there, compared to the attempted solution here. This method could be inconsistent in case of multiple occurences of a letter, IMHO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding if two words are anagrams of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236906/finding-if-two-words-are-anagrams-of-each-other)

Comment: @HerbWolfe Possible duplicate of [my comment just above yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53747962/i-don%c2%b4t-find-the-mistake-of-my-code-to-check-strings-for-anagram?noredirect=1#comment94351734_53747962) :P

Comment: @P.Soutzikevich Hehe, nice one :D

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public boolean anagram (String s1, String s2) {
    int count = 0;
    boolean a = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
        int s1index = s1.indexOf(s2.charAt(i));
        if (s1index != -1) {
        count++;
        s1 = s1.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(s1.charAt(s1index)),"");
        } 
    }
    if ((count == s2.length()) && (s1.length() == 0))
        a = true;
    return a;
    }
```

Basically the test should be done at the end of the function and outside the `for` loop, and you'd want to return the boolean value of `a`, not the boolean value of `a == true` (which should be always `false`, since `a` is never assigned the `true` value in your code).

EDIT: I've corrected two mistakes in my initial answer, as well as added code that will hopefully eliminate the issue of multiple occurences of a letter (which is why my first answer didn't work in some cases). This code modifies the `s1` string - if you don't want that, just do `s1temp = s1;` at the beginning of the function and replace `s1` with `s1temp` for the rest of the function. The code also uses string's `replaceFirst()` method - since the `replace` method deletes **all** occurences of a letter as far as I know, but you can switch to other alternatives that delete a character from a string (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386107/how-to-remove-single-character-from-a-string) for further details). By the way, your `temp` approach was incorrectly trying to replace the **index** of a character, not the actual character, not to mention the fact that a `i !=-1` test makes no sense in a `for` loop that is incrementing `i` starting from 0.

NOTE: You can verify if it's working (with every step printed out on the screen) [here](http://tpcg.io/bclzDA) (online Java compiler).

Comment: Thank you for the expression :).
The solution worked :)

Comment: Please consider selecting this answer as the solution to your question and also voting-up for the user's effort in solving your problem :)
*Have a wonderful day!*

Comment: @BastianoCoimbra You're welcome - good luck at school ;)

Comment: If I test for the strings "anna" and "aaaa"  it also return true with this code. But why ? I can´t understand this. Because it should stop count++, after he deleted the 2 a´s of anna and should stop when he try to find the next char, because it should return -1.

Comment: @BastianoCoimbra I've updated my answer to try to correct the issue you mentioned - let me know if it works. Sorry for the delay, I've been busy all day :)

Comment: thank you, the new solution works fine. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: It was actually my first Java answer (and code), LOL. I was mistakenly under the impression that it was Javascript at first, and then after answering and realizing my error I just went with the flow. You could mark an answer (not necessarily mine) as the accepted one, if it helped you, of course.

Answer (score 1):

My solution does not modify immutable `Strings` (i.e. create new modified string instnce) and temporary array with size 26:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String one, String two) {
    one = one != null ? one.toLowerCase() : "";
    two = two != null ? two.toLowerCase() : "";

    if (one.length() != two.length())
        return false;

    int[] arr = new int[26];

    for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++)
        arr[one.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
    for (int i = 0; i < two.length(); i++)
        arr[two.charAt(i) - 'a']--;
    for (int ch : arr)
        if (ch != 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I like this one. A short explanation on what happens within those arrays would help the less savvy though.